# How to subtract differences from similar images in order to obtain the background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I have 4 images, all with the same original background, every single one of them has writing somewhere in the picture, if compared 1 to 1, the only difference would be the writing, I wan't to extract the pieces of background from each of the images in order to build the whole background back.

Image:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

if all the difference are substracted, it can be achieved the background without text (and no contant-aware fill):

[image]

What I managed to do, which is really bad and time consuming:

1. Select -> Color range
2. Select all color from text
3. Select -> Modify -> Expand by 2 pixel
4. Delete
5. Merge all of them together

This will leave JPEG artifacts and also won't be a real substraction, there are probably a term for what I'm trying to do, but since I don't know how it is, I arranged this title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with a *Stack*.

- Select *File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack*.
- Click *Browse* and select your images. Make sure to check *Create Smart Object after Loading Layers*.

[image]

Now your images have been stacked on top of each other and packed into a Smart Object.

[image]

- Make sure the Smart Object is selected and select *Layer > Smart Objects > Stack Mode > Minimum*.

[image]